# Does Roboto come standard in android studio?

Tags: android, fonts, android-studio, roboto

Does the Roboto font family come standard in Android Studio? Or do I have to add it the way I would for eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it bellow android 4.0 you will have to package it as an asset, it doesn't have nothing to do with the IDE that you are using.

Comment: Roboto fonts were added in the Android 4.0, not 5.0.